# Adding a tag to UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have an array of an object (which contains an image and some text) and when I iterate around the array and add the image to a `UIImageView` (which is then added to a `UIScrollView`) all works well and each image is added with a specific `UIImageView` to the `UIScrollView`.

However as soon as I add a tag to the `UIImageView` not all the images are rendered within the added `UIImageView` (which is in the `UIScrollView` (some are missing, some are visible).

If I remove the tag, all works well? Is there something with tags I'm not grasping? Any help much appreciated.

```
for (Article *al in articleLists){

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.FeaturedView.frame.size.width * counter;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.FeaturedView.frame.size;

        CGRect frameTextArea;
        frameTextArea.origin.x = self.FeaturedView.frame.size.width * counter;
        frameTextArea.origin.y = (self.FeaturedView.frame.size.height / 2) + 10;
        frameTextArea.size.width = self.FeaturedView.frame.size.width;
        frameTextArea.size.height = (self.FeaturedView.frame.size.height / 2) - 20;

        CGRect frameTextLabel;
        frameTextLabel.origin.x = (self.FeaturedView.frame.size.width * counter) + 20;
        frameTextLabel.origin.y = (self.FeaturedView.frame.size.height / 2) + 10;
        frameTextLabel.size.width = self.FeaturedView.frame.size.width - 40;
        frameTextLabel.size.height = (self.FeaturedView.frame.size.height / 2) - 20;

        if (al.imageURL != NULL){

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            //imageView.tag = counter;
            imageView.image = al.imageArticle;
            UITapGestureRecognizer *imageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
            [imageView addGestureRecognizer:imageTap];
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIView *viewTextArea = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frameTextArea];
            viewTextArea.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            viewTextArea.alpha = 0.9;

            UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameTextLabel];
            textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
            textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Droid Sans" size:18];
            textLabel.text = [al.currentTitle uppercaseString];

            [self.FeaturedView addSubview:imageView];
            [self.FeaturedView addSubview:viewTextArea];
            [self.FeaturedView addSubview:textLabel];

        }
        else{
            //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ArticlePlaceholder.png"];
        }

        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: can you add some screenshots or something?

Comment: not at all. maybe you are setting same tag to many UIImageViews and your code just remove duplicate in some way.

Comment: Now that's REALLY weird, tags shouldn't have absolutely anything to do with Views. Unless, somewhere in your code, you're doing something based on UIImageView.tag.

Comment: Why you don't use a UICollectionView ?

Comment: I've added my code to the original post, again all works until I add in the imageView.tag = counter; then either the first or second image is missing, all the UILabels are fine.

Comment: I fixed it, I was removing a Activity indicator just after the iteration and that had a tag id of 1;

So this was interfering with the image tag.

Thanks all and to Lord Zsolt which pointed me in the right direction with this